# short-circuit evaluation with three variables

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following code, thinking it would fail to work because it would go like this: "if it is not running and the ID matches this one, execute the code" disregarding the cap on the break size:

```
if(!isRunning && id==="break-increment" && breakvar<=59){
this.setState((state) => ({
  break: this.state.break +1}))}
```

Much to my surprise, it worked. But I don´t really understand why. Wouldn´t it fail because the cap size would never be evaluated?

Comment: what is the value of `breakvar`?... There must be some default value like `0` or `null`

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. `breakvar` won't be disregarded. If it's > 59, the test will be false.

Comment: breakvar has a default value, yes (it´s 5). My question is: how does Javascript evaluate the second part of the statement? I thought short-circuit meant it would just evaluate isRunning and id.

Comment: It will only short circuit if `!isRunning` is false because it doesn't need to test the rest of the statement.

Comment: Okay. So the second part gets evaluated as one because of the parentheses, right?

Comment: Actually there is no use of parentheses here.... Without parentheses it would give you same result.....i.e. three conditions

Comment: I thought you  couldn´t have three conditions without short-circuiting (eg, if isRunning is false then it only evaluates id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought you couldn´t have three conditions without short-circuiting (eg, if isRunning is false then it only evaluates id)

No.

If `!isRunning` is false, the first `&&` short circuits and is evaluated as its LHS (false) without evaluating the RHS.

If `!isRunning` is true, the first `&&` doesn't short circuit and is evaluated as its RHS (`id==="break-increment" && breakvar<=59`)

Comment: Thank you. But if I added one more condition to the RHS (eg, id==="break-increment" && breakvar<=59 && breakvar >=2"), THAT would short-circuit, right?

Comment: @HernanAriel — Only if the LHS of the `&&` is falsy